# e.preventDefault() is not working on div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault

preventDefault() is not working on div onclick, i tried preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation also nothing works, please see the below sample.

```
<title></title>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $().ready(function () {
        $("div").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        });

        //$("div").bind("click", function (e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false; });

    });

</script>
```

```
<div onclick="alert('1');">

    Sample text

</div>
```

Comment: How do you know its not working, i.e. what default behaviour are you seeing or ancestor element's events are you observing?

Comment: You cannot ensure your binded event will be the first to be run. Did you tried $('div').removeAttr('onclick') ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no *default behaviour* of clicking on a `div`. What are you trying to prevent?

Also `event.stopPropagation()` is to stop the event from bubbling up ancestors and triggering their event handlers. What is it triggering in your case?

Comment: hi i am trying to prevent alert defined on div onclick event, first alert is firing then e.preventdefault is executing

Comment: I think this happens because jQuery appends your ***.click()*** event at the end of the events declared directly into the DOM. Also, like Alex stated, `alert("1")` is a custom event, not the *default behaviour*.